# How to add link, pic or apply css style to browser alert window?

Tags: javascript, css, alert

In the Google Hangouts page click the "Available for your computer" button will popup an alert window witch contains pictures and a link.

[Google Hangouts page](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/)

I wonder how google acchieve this.

Anyone know?

UPDATE: I'm here to ask because I don't think other questions are solved this question.
I can believe the dialog box is not a plugin but the build in one. So I want to know how it works.

[image: Google Hangouts page]

Comment: I doubt that's a native browser alert window...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a javascript based modal instead like [Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

As `Alert()` being a part of the browser, it cannot be styled with CSS.

Hope this helps.